# command terminated in attempt to assign a variable

Tags: c, terminate

Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

   char *str = "foo\n"; //if 'char str[] = "foo\n";' no problem
   char *c = strchr(str, '\n');
   *c='\0'; //causes "command terminated"
   // *(c+0)='c'    does not help

   return 0;
}
```

I have no idea, why program crash, when I got `c` pointer from `strchr` and then dereference it in assignment.

Comment: you try to modify the literal string`"foo\n"` which is read only. replace `char *str = "foo\n";` by `char str[] = "foo\n";`

Comment: I don't understand. I have not added `const` modifier to var `str` to be read-only. Why can I then modify it, when is used array instead of pointer (as in comments of code)?

Comment: yes but a literal string is readonly anyway

Comment: `char str[] foo`, is also literal string, and yet can modify

Comment: no, a literal string is `"..."`, but having `char str[] = "foo\n";` *str* is not a literal string, it is just initialized using a form with a literal string

Comment: if you try to modify an element declared `const` or directely a literal you have an error at *compile time*, if you try to modify a read-only element while you was able to compile you have an error at the *execution time*. In C is is possible to write `char * p = "aze";` but that  changes nothing on the fact *p* point to a read only string. Anyway it is better to use `const char * p = "aze";` for the clarity of the source